# Making the enableidentityplatform google rest api a aserver or client side request returns CORs error but works on postman

Tags: c#, google-api, cors

Making identity platform enable rest api from c# not working when requested from client side. I wanted to make an endpoint that will enable identity platform, but I keep getting CORS error when I make api call from angular, even though I added a header to allow any origin. It works as expected in postman but when I make this request from client side app to server I keep getting CORS issue. How to fix this issue ?

```
[HttpPost]
        public  async Task<HttpResponseMessage> EnableIdentityPlatformApi1([FromBody] ConfigParamModel _request)
        {
            try
            {

               
                var projectId = _request.AppName;
                string sCurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                string sFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sCurrentDirectory, @"./application_default_credentials.json");
                string pathToCreds = Path.GetFullPath(sFile);
                GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(pathToCreds);
                // var credential = await GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync();
                var accessToken = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
                var payload = new {                
                    

                };            

                // Serialize the payload to JSON
                string payloadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    RequestUri = new Uri($"https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{projectId}/identityPlatform:initializeAuth"),
                    Content = new StringContent(payloadJson, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
                };
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                request.Headers.Add("x-goog-user-project", projectId);
                request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");


                // Send the request
                // var myresponse = client.Send(request);
                var myresponse = await client.SendAsync(request);
                
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(true);
                response.Content = new StringContent(JSONresult, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                response.Content = new StringContent(ex.Message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                return response;
            }
        }
```

Error :

```
Acess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/postman-project1/identityPlatform:initializeAuth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zo
```